# Existe alguma função Java equivalente ao var_dump()?

Tags: php, java

Alguém sabe se existe alguma função Java equivalente ao `var_dump()`?

Comment: Não existe algo pronto igual no PHP, no Java você teria que implementar isto usando o método [`Class.html#getDeclaredFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()).

Comment: Eu sei Java mas não sei bem PHP. Qual seria a funcionalidade do `var_dump()`?

Comment: Esta resposta lhe foi útil?

Answer (score 1):

> Não existe equivalente igual em java, porem encontrei uma solução que pode lhe ser util no SOen ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301536/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-php-var-dump)), irei traduzir ela abaixo:

Suas alternativas são substituir o método `toString()` do objeto para a saída do seu conteúdo de uma maneira que lhe atenda, ou usar reflexão para inspecionar o objeto (de forma semelhante ao que os depuradores fazem).

A vantagem de usar a reflexão é que você não precisará modificar seus objetos individuais para ser "analisável", porem é adicionada complexidade e se você precisar suportar um objeto aninhado você vai ter que escrever isso.

```
Field[] fields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (int i=0; i<fields.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(fields[i].getName() + " - " + fields[i].get(o));
}
```